# Scroll to top on click for a sub drop down menu in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, dreamweaver

I like to access content from sub drop down menu immediately without using scroll bar on left hand side as shown in the figure using html

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Here is the code I used

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <br/>
    <button class="collapsible">Drop Down Main</button>
        <div class="content"><p></p>
     <ul>
        <button class="collapsible">Drop Down-1</button>
        <div class="content"><p></p>
        <p>Line1 </p>
        <p>Line 2</p>
        <p><b>Line 3</b></p>
        </div>
        </ul>
            
            
        <ul>
        <button class="collapsible">Drop Down-2</button>
        <div class="content"><p></p>
        <p>Line1 </p>
        <p>Line 2</p>
        <p> <b>Line 3</b></p>   
        </div>
        </ul>
            
        <ul>
          <button class="collapsible">Drop Down-3</button>
        <div class="content"><p></p>
        <p>Line1 </p>
        <p>Line 2</p>
        <p> <b>Line 3</b></p>       
        </div>
        </ul>
            
<ul>
        <button class="collapsible">Drop Down-4</button>
        <div class="content"><p></p>
            <p>Line1 </p>
            <p>Line 2</p>
            <p> <b>Line 3</b></p>       
            </div>
        </ul>   
    </div>
    <br/>
```

This is the style code I used for drop down and sub drop downs.

```
.collapsible {
  background-color: #01579b;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
   width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #0043b3;
}
    
.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;

}
```

Please let me know how we can use html to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: will you like `javascript` ?

Comment: @Neptotech -vishnu, please suggest the solution with javascript, I am using Dreamweaver by the way and like to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the standard [`<details>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) HTML element:

```js
let details = document.querySelectorAll('details>details');

// add toggle event on all sub sections
details.forEach(d => {
  d.addEventListener("toggle", event => {
    let current = event.target;
    // close all others
    if (current.open){
      details.forEach(e => {
        if (current !== e) e.open = false;
      });
     
       current.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "center", inline: "nearest"});
     }
  });
});
```

```css
body{
 padding: 1rem;
}
summary {
  background-color: rgb(46, 46, 255);
  color: white;
  padding: 0.3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

details>details {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

details>details>summary {
  background-color: rgb(86, 86, 245);
}

details>details[open]>summary {
  background-color: rgb(105, 166, 245);
}

details .info {
  padding: .5rem;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Drop down main</summary>
  <details>
    <summary>Drop down 1</summary>
    <div class="info">ONE Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, sunt.</div>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary>Drop down 2</summary>
    <div class="info">TWO Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, illo exercitationem sequi voluptatum tempora minus rem amet magnam. Necessitatibus nihil dolores eaque sed quaerat ducimus aliquid cupiditate impedit quam laboriosam odit sequi,
      numquam fuga neque! Optio aut at, omnis quasi amet cum rem id fuga velit error cupiditate commodi neque.</div>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary>Drop down 3</summary>
    <div class="info">THREE Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto ad saepe ex obcaecati expedita nulla, nihil laborum esse excepturi natus amet non eligendi atque sint. Tenetur molestias perspiciatis libero perferendis, autem earum et eius numquam
      repellat commodi sint dignissimos veritatis eaque ratione voluptatum nam molestiae voluptatibus ipsum illum! Id dolor quos consequuntur vero cumque tenetur, quaerat quam odit non illum exercitationem voluptates! Minima, quia dolore? Accusamus libero?</div>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary>Drop down 4</summary>
    <div class="info">FOUR Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cupiditate nobis odio iusto, ratione laborum ipsa tempora eos porro repellat recusandae dolore quasi adipisci explicabo consequuntur omnis eveniet asperiores culpa!</div>
  </details>
</details>
```

We can use [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) to bring element in view. Play with the method arguments to get desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html as an anchor tag
like for me a navbar:

html:

```
<nav class="navbar background h-nav-resp">
      <ul class=" navlist v-class-resp">
        
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    
      <div class="rightNav v-class-resp">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
        <button class="btn btn-sm">search</button>
      </div>

      <div class="burger">
          <div class="line"></div>
          <div class="line"></div>
          <div class="line"></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

and then I will just give the ID to every place as In I gave in my nav:

```
<section class="background firstSection" id="home">
      <div class="box-main">
        <div class="firsthalf">
          <p class="text-big">The future of education is here!</p>
          <p class="text-small">
            In this country of 7 Billion we need to educate each and all of them
            and we are proud to say that The future of education is here.
          </p>
          <div class="buttons">
            <button class="btn">subscribe</button>
            <button class="btn">watch video</button>
          </div>

          <div class="secondhalf">
            <img src="img/Laptop.jpg" alt="laptop image" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="section" id="about">
      <div class="paras">
        <p class="SectionTag text-big">The end of your search is here.</p>
        <p class="SectionSubTag text-small">
          Education is about learning skills and knowledge. It also means
          helping people to learn how to do things and support them to think
          about what they learn. It's also important for educators to teach ways
          to find and use information. Education needs research to find out how
          to make it better. It helps people become better citizens, get a
          better-paid job, shows the difference between good and bad. Education
          shows us the importance of hard work and, at the same time, helps us
          grow and develop. Thus, we are able to shape a better society to live
          in by knowing and respecting rights, laws, and regulations.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img
          src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900×700/?Html"
          alt="laptop image"
          class="imgfluid"
        />
      </div>
    </section>
    <hr />
    <section class="section left" id="services">
      <div class="paras">
        <p class="SectionTag text-big">When coding meets children in India</p>
        <p class="SectionSubTag text-small">
          Through coding, students build essential literacy skills, gain an
          understanding of logic and sequence, and learn the mechanics of
          iteration. These tools support project-based learning and give
          students the freedom to create, collaborate, hack, remix, and tinker
          with their own unique designs.Coding classes are currently limited to
          people with a laptop, internet connection, and paying capacity.
          Further, very little content is available in the field which is
          suitable for children and apt from the Indian context.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img
          src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900×700/?Javascript"
          alt="laptop image"
          class="imgfluid"
        />
      </div>
    </section>
    <hr />
    <section class="section">
      <div class="paras">
        <p class="SectionTag text-big">Why is programming useful?</p>
        <p class="SectionSubTag text-small">
          Programming also teaches them how software engineers use math in order
          to solve problems in a logical and creative way. This is an important
          reason that coding should be taught in schools, so children learn
          these skills while they are young.Coding, to put it simply, is using
          computer language to tell a computer what to do. The skills necessary
          for coding include being able to analyze a problem, break it down,
          engage critical thinking, and logic. This “thinking” element is often
          referred to as computational thinking.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img
          src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900×700/?laptop"
          alt="laptop image"
          class="imgfluid"
        />
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="contact" >
      <h1 class="text-center" id="contact">Contact Us</h1>
      <div class="form">
        <input
          class="form-input"
          type="name"
          name="name"
          id="name"
          placeholder="enter your name"
        />
        <input
          class="form-input"
          type="phone"
          name="Phone"
          id="phone"
          placeholder="enter your phone"
        />
        <input
          class="form-input"
          type="email"
          name="email"
          id="email"
          placeholder="enter your email"
        />
        <textarea class="form-input" name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10" maxlength="290" wrap="soft" placeholder="Elaborate your concern"></textarea>

        <button class="btn btn-dark">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </section>

    <footer class="background">
        <p class="text-footer">
            Copyright saraswati education-giving eduction online.com &copy; 2022 - All rights reserved
        </p>
        <div class="designer"><p>Designed and developed by pranjal Rai</p></div>
    </footer>
```

If you click on the link it will scroll at that position but!
add this

css:

```
html{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

It makes it good!

Answer (score 0):

Add one onclick even to the element with return false

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">
```

this will stop scrolling the page to the top